# Replacing 0 values of np array with nan in an easy way

Tags: python, numpy, nan

It seems in principle an np array can hold nan values but it does not like them to be written into after initial allocation? Can anybody shed light on this and maybe suggest an easier way of how to do the replacement than what I have in example 5?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2,1,0,7])
a[a==0] = -999  # replacing this way with numbers works
print (a)

a = np.array([2,1,np.nan,7])  # allocating an np array with nans works
print (a)

a = np.array([2,1,0,7])
a[a==0] = np.nan   # trying the frist approach with nan instead of a number gives ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

a = np.array([2,1,0,7])
a[2] = np.nan   #  also writing to one specific position does not work: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
print (a)

# works - but this cant be the way to do it normally?
a = np.array([2,1,0,7])
a = list(a)
for idx, elem in enumerate(a):
    if elem == 0:
        a[idx] = np.nan
a = np.array(a)
print(a)
```

Comment: The error is quite explicit. The problem is that `a` is of type `int`, and `np.nan` is of type `float`, so it cannot by directly assigned nor cast to int since it is only defined for float types

Comment: `a = a.astype(np.float64); a[a == 0] = np.nan`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
np.array([2,1,0,7]).dtype
# => dtype('int64')
np.array([2,1,np.nan,7]).dtype
# => dtype('float64')
```

Integers don't have a NaN value; `np.nan` is a float, and can't be placed in an integral array.

roganjosh beat me to the solution though :P (i.e. convert to a float array before trying to put a `np.nan` in there). With roganjosh's permission:

```
a = np.array([2,1,0,7])
a = a.astype(np.float64)
a[a == 0] = np.nan
a
# => array([ 2.,  1., nan,  7.])
```

The reason why converting to `list` works is the fact that lists, unlike numpy arrays, don't mind mixing element types. When you re-convert a mixed list of integers and floats, numpy will assume you wanted a float array.

Comment: tbf, I first repeated the mistake with the integers :) Just add to your answer, they could probably get away with `float32` with their example or even less

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is that a is of type `int`, and `np.nan` is of type float, so it cannot by directly assigned nor cast to int since it is only defined for float types.

You'd have to initialize an array of floats for the slice assignment to work:

```
a = np.array([2,1,0,7], dtype=float)
a[a==0] = np.nan

print(a)
# array([ 2.,  1., nan,  7.])
```